# How to give guest user access to specific folder

Tags: permissions

I have a folder called /media/user1/folder/subfolder

I created a non root user called guest

Now when i try to access /media/user1/folder/subfolder, it says permission denied.

I tried doing

```
sudo chown guest /media/user1/folder/subfolder
```

from user1, but i still cannot access it in guest. Help!

Comment: What command did you use to create the user named `guest` and what are the permissions of the directory `/media/user1/folder/subfolder` and its parents?  Please [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: drwxrwxrwx+  5 guest guest 4.0K Sep 25 14:04 subfolder

Comment: The issue is that the parent folder's i dont want the user to have access to

Comment: drwxr--r--  20 user1 user1 4.0K Sep 25 20:55 folder

Comment: I must add that this /media/user1 folder is owned by root as well

Comment: The user `guest` needs execute permissions on all the directories leading up to and including the target folder.